# ASP.NET Json Exception

Tags: asp.net, jsonexception

We have a group project and when I clone repistory from my teammate I have this error. This project works on everyone in the team but me.

```
JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

This is where error leads me:

```
<GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest
      Source="$(PackageId)"
      BasePath="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath)"
      Mode="$(StaticWebAssetProjectMode)"
      ManifestType="Build"
      ReferencedProjectsConfigurations="@(StaticWebAssetProjectConfiguration)"
      DiscoveryPatterns="@(StaticWebAssetDiscoveryPattern)"
      Assets="@(StaticWebAsset)"
      ManifestPath="$(StaticWebAssetBuildManifestPath)">
    </GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest>
```

How can I solve this?

I tried clean solution and rebuild solution. It doesn't work

Comment: The error says you tried to parse a string that doesn't contain JSON but either HTML or XML. `GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest` isn't directly related to the error. That's the build task that encountered the problem. Have you tried *deleting* the `bin` and `obj` folders? `Clean Solution` doesn't delete everything in them.

Comment: The error could be caused by a corrupt file too. Or if you clone a repository with the wrong newline settings. That results in what to the compiler is a corrupt file